# Авария: с чем или чего?

Tags: согласование

"Сегодня на заводе произошла авария оборудования, в результате чего оно вышло из строя". В данном случае понятно: авария - чего? Оборудования. Но вместе с этим читаем: "Авария с самолетом на Украиной унесла жизни около трехсот человек". И в данном случае мы видим: авария с чем? С самолетом.
А в чем, собственно, разница? Почему в случае станка на заводе будет авария чего-то, а в случае транспорта - с чем-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

АВАРИЯ 1.Повреждение, выход из строя какого-л. механизма, машины,  время действия, движения.2. Крушение, катастрофа, вызванные таким повреждением, нарушением правил безопасности движения, погодными условиями и т.п. Попасть в аварию. Самолёт потерпел аварию.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Возможно использование обоих вариантов:

(1) Выход из строя (чего)

Авария «Прогресса» (точнее, ракеты-носителя, на которой он должен был выводиться на орбиту) стала последней каплей в череде космических неудач России. На 261-й секунде, когда, по расчетам, должно было произойти отделение второй ступени, появилась раскачка по тангажу, затем раздался пронзительный вой сирены и замигало красное табло «Авария носителя».

(2) Авария как инцидент:

(С чем?) авария с рейсовым автобусом, авария с почтово-багажным поездом или (где? когда) авария на Чернобыльской АЭС, авария при выводе ракеты на траекторию.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, согласно словарю Д. Э. Розенталя " Управление в русском языке" возможны оба варианта. Авария чего и с чем.